# Certain Objects in DOM do not seem to render despite being in the HTML source?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm quite new to web dev, and I've encountered the following odd issue. While using `d3.js` (specifically [this script](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd)), I've been trying to add some other features. I've added a feature in my javascript code that adds a simple `<p>` to the DOM, and when I render it on my website and inspect source, I see it is indeed there. Here is a subset of the relevant HTML:

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(180, 37.5)" style="stroke: rgb(128, 128, 128);">
    <circle class="node" r="10" id="node_2" cursor="pointer" style="fill: lightsteelblue;"></circle>
    <text dy=".35em" x="-13" text-anchor="end">2</text></g>
    <p>hello</p>
```

I added the `<p>hello</p>` tag, and what's strange to me is that every other element is rendered (a circle is drawn, and the text "2" is present) but there is no "hello" to be seen. I tried replacing the `p` tag with `div` and `span`, but none will render the text except using the actual `<text>` tag. Usually, when I hover over HTML in my Browser (Chrome), the element represented by that HTML is highlighted, but hovering over the `<p>` tag yields nothing.

Could someone explain why this is, and offer a potential fix please? For context, I'm not just interested in adding text here; I want to be able to render some more complicated components, which will require being able to render other HTML element types as children of the `g` object.

Comment: I am too lacy to check the spec, but could it be that HTML tags are not allowed inside SVG?

Comment: @pintxo Ah, it seems like I should use the <foreignobject> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hugo's answer is also good. For my purposes, I found the addition of the `foreignobject` tag was the best solution:

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(180, 37.5)" style="stroke: rgb(128, 128, 128);">
    <circle class="node" r="10" id="node_2" cursor="pointer" style="fill: lightsteelblue;"></circle>
    <text dy=".35em" x="-13" text-anchor="end">2</text></g>
    <foreignobject width="100" height = "100">
       <p>hello</p>
    </foreignobject>
```

A couple notes:

- This allows for nesting of elements in the SVG element, which may be helpful when it's not easy to restructure the DOM elements.
- For some reason (I'm not completely sure why), it's important to specify the `width` and `height` attribute of the `foreignobject`; otherwise, it might not render.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to overlay your HTML children on top of the SVG with `position: absolute:`

```
<div class="container">
    <svg></svg>
    <p id="text">hello</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container #text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```